# Why is polysome loading affected by double stranded structure?

Tags: gene-expression

Why polysomes are not able to load properly onto a transcript if a transcript has a double-stranded structure in it?

Comment: You mean to say a single ribosome is loaded but multiple ribosomes are not loading? Do you have any data on this or you just heard it somewhere? Usually secondary structures are resolved by elongation factors (4A). In general secondary structures will impede ribosome movement. You should add more details in your question.

Comment: I was reading the following article "C. elegans and H. sapiens mRNAs with edited 3′ UTRs are present on polysomes". According to it, polysomes are not able to load properly on to the transcript if two inverted alu repeats make a double stranded structure within a transcript.